# Software to search XML files which match an XPath

Tags: software-development, .net, xml, search

I've got some XML files which are .NET configuration files (app.config, web.config). You can read [the specification on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fk1t1t0(v=vs.90).aspx).

My problem is very specific but it can easily be generalized.
In a [client / server model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model) of WCF the application which behave as clients have, in their configuration file, the following instructions.

```
<client>
  <endpoint name="AuthenticationServiceEndpoint" address="http://mydomain/AuthenticationService" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpWithMessageSecurityWithoutAuthentication" behaviorConfiguration="NoCertificateCheckEndpointBehavior" contract="WCF.Services.Contracts.IAuthenticationService">
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

The application which behave as Server has similar config files. But it's in an XML node called `<server>` instead of `<client>`.

I am looking for an application which allows me to search all the files a folder and its subfolders which match a syntax like XPath or easier to use.

I want it simple, with preview, syntax highlighting, expression checking. 
Do you know anything similar?

Comment: Maybe [XPath Visualizer](https://xpathvisualizer.codeplex.com/)? I have used that occasionally, but don't know enough about XPath to make this a proper recommendation.

Comment: @JanDoggen: thanks, it's not exactly what I'm looking for but nice!